# Safe navigation operator in Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, operators, conditional-operator

I use safe navigation operator to avoid NPEs like this

```
myInstance?.field1
myInstance?.field2
myInstance?.field3
```

To convert the code above in for loop i wrote

```
<g:each var="i" in="${ (1..<4 }">
    myInstance['field'+i]
</g:each>
```

How do I use the safe navigation operator on above code when I am retrieving values in hashmap format?
I looked into docs [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators) but it does not have a similar example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use this syntax:

```
myInstance?."field$i"
```

Comment: This worked, but is there a guide line on when to use single quotes and when to use double? I use them interchangeably but in this case only double quotes worked!

Comment: Double quotes work because along with the embedded expression (`$i`) it makes a GString, and there's special handling to get a property or invoke a method dynamically this way.

Answer (score 5):

You could do:

```
<g:each var="i" in="${ (1..<4 }">
    ${myInstance?."field$i"}
</g:each>
```

Or, probably better (and neater in your code) would be to [make this a tag](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#taglibs) and do it as you would above inside the pure groovy tag.